# xampp loading image problems

Tags: html, xampp

everyone i'm just starting to learn code and having trouble getting images to appear. i'm using xampp. The alt text seem to shows up when I view the code in the browser but no image. im using a windows. here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> <title> fitness </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\xampp\htdocs\static\css\rsstylesheet.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="nav">
 <ul>
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="">Fitness</a></li>
<li><a href="">About</a></li>
<li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>

 <img src="‪C:\xampp\htdocs\static\css\background.jpg" alt="background" width="200px" height="200px" />

 <h2> fitness</h2>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your src.

At the moment you are referring your whole path, but you only need the part after the location of your file.

So if your file is in the 'htdocs' folder and your image is in the 'static/css/' folder, you can just add 'static/css/' before your image and you are good to go.

You might also consider changing '\' to '/'.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i switched my code but, it still didn't work                                      <img src='static/css/background.jpg' alt="background" width="200px" height="200px" />

Comment: @kyle Are you sure your background is jpg format and you do not have any spaces anywhere? You might also want to try loading the html without xampp to see if xampp is causing the problem or not.

Comment: i looked through the pictures properties and copy and pasted the object name, so it should be the correct path?  i turned off xampp and still the same problem.

Comment: @kyle then the problem is in your html. But I'm afraid I can't really help you since I don't have much more information to go on.